# MSBuild Bootstrapper postrequisite

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapping

Hello I am using the MSBuild Bootstrapper for my Visual Studio 2005 project. I need to have a specific version of DirectX installed with my program. The problem is I am unable to catch and defer the reboot after DirectX gets installed. I dont know why it wont catch it. So my new idea is to have DirectX be installed after my program is. Then it can reboot at the end and things should work. But I dont know how to specify a postrequisite in the XML. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not familiar with the MSBuild bootstrapper but i use [dotnetinstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) and there you can have the component install order without problem